# Update table using another table and INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I get an issue using `update` and `inner join` with MYSQL.

I need to concat properties using another table.

My query :

```
update cfc_registration
 set teams = concat(r.teams, " - ", u.firstname, " ", u.lastname)
 from cfc_registration as r
 inner join cfc_user as u
 on r.cfcUserId = u.id
 where r.cfcTournamentId = 5
```

Error message :

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from cfc_registration as r inner join cfc_user as u on r.cfcUserId = u.id whe' at line 3
```

Comment: try it first -> .. `SET r.teams = concat(r.teams, u.firstname, u.lastname) as ConcatString`

Comment: With `set r. teams = concat(r.teams, " - ", u.firstname, " ", u.lastname) as ConcatString`, I get the same error message.

Comment: well, try it simple first, without concat ->.. `set r.teams = u.firstname`.. if it works then try concat without double quotes.

Comment: "Update from"..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure `FROM` and `INNER JOIN` can be used in an update query. Try this instead:

```
update cfc_registration r, cfc_user u
set teams = concat(r.teams, " - ", u.firstname, " ", u.lastname)
where r.cfcTournamentId = 5 and r.cfcUserId = u.id
```

Comment: hey i dont want to be rude but very slight post edit get rejected,

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE cfc_registration as r
inner join cfc_user as u
on r.cfcUserId = u.id
and r.cfcTournamentId = 5 set teams = concat(r.teams, " - ", u.firstname, " ",    u.lastname)
```